# parametrized Factory Method Pattern

Tags: java, factory-method

The explanation is long, but the examples are very simple and basic.

I would like to create a Reader object through a Factory Method Pattern, because actually i have an IniReader and an XmlReader, both subclasses of Reader. 
The choice of the concrete class is made at runtime on the basis of the type of a file, and in the future the application should handle other file formats.

My question is: for this simple problem, does make sense trying to apply factory method pattern?

The attempt to apply this pattern has led to degenerate classes that contains just a `new MyObject()` call. Sometimes being "simple" means "easily changeable in the future without breaking the client", i think to the getter/setter methods, often one-lined. But this seems not the case.

My very basic implementation:

```
public interface Reader {
   //does nothing, it's a sample!
   //obviously it would have at least a read method declaration
}

//my concrete IniReader
public class IniReader implements Reader{}

//my concrete XmlReader
public class XmlReader implements Reader{}
```

Then, at the heart of my factory method pattern, i have an abstract ReaderCreator:

```
public abstract class ReaderCreator {
    abstract Reader create();
}
```

and its two concrete subclasses:

```
public class IniReaderCreator extends ReaderCreator {
    @Override Reader create() {
        return new IniReader();
    }
}

public class XmlReaderCreator extends ReaderCreator{
    @Override Reader create() {
        return new XmlReader();
    }
}
```

At this point, i need to determine the file i have, instantiate the right ReaderCreator and let it instantiate the right reader.
I am tempted to create a parametrized factory method to the ReaderCreator abstract (thus the method has to be static), like this:

```
public static ReaderCreator newInstance(File f) {
    if (f.getName().endsWith(".ini")) {
        return new IniReaderCreator();
    } else if (f.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
        return new XmlReaderCreator(); 
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File type not handled");
    }
}
```

but this is NOT a parametrized factory method, but rather another "factory method" idiom over the factory pattern. 
Nevertheless this seems to me to be the most obvious implementation of the pattern. 
I've just pulled into ReaderCreator the method that (maybe in the client) decides between IniReaderCreator and XmlReaderCreator.

The parametrized factory method is really something different  because it states that all the subclasses of ReaderCreator reimplement the decision-maker algorithm that choiches between IniReader and XmlReader, that in this case would be obviously absurd (a XmlReaderConstructor that implements a `create` method that returns a IniReader?).

Answer (score 1):

i'd go with your factory method idiom for now and maybe even have it construct and return the appropriate reader. this seems like an example of [Refactoring To Patterns](http://industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/)